# How to update Field Name in Solr Collection?

Tags: solr

I have a solr indexed data as below.
My requirement is to update the field name MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_YEAR which is actually a date to MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_DATE.
The data is in Millions, which will take more time to re-index.

Is there any way from Solr UI to update the field name, without re-indexing the whole data?

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":39,
    "params":{
      "q":"SOLR_DATA",
      "_":"1607925693065"}},
  "response":{"numFound":129500000,"start":0,"maxScore":5.632038,"docs":[
      {
        "PLANT":["HYD"],
        "STOCK_TYPE":[""],
        "Table_Name":["TBL_MATERIAL_DOC_DISPLAY"],
        "MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_YEAR":["20140312"],
        "MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION":["T-SHIRT-XXL"],
        "MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_NUMBER":["12345678"],
        "MOVEMENT_TYPE":["123"],
        "COST_CENTER":[""],
```

Comment: There is no way to rename the field without re-indexing....may be you can add another field with correct name ...once it is added for all the fields then you can remove the earlier incorrect field...

Comment: Second approach would be create another collection with correct field names ...once all the data is up to date in new collection then you can create an alias to it with earlier collection name...then remove the older index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to rename the field without re-indexing and modifying the the schema.xml
May be you can add another field with correct name.
once it is added for all the fields then you can remove the earlier incorrect field.

Second option would be create another collection with correct field names.
Once all the data is up to date in new collection then you can create an alias to it with earlier collection name.

Once done with all the above you can then remove the older index...